# Broadcast message not being received

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, broadcast, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to create a widget with 2 clickable buttons, which have their handlers attached to them using the onUpdate method in the AppWidgetProvider. However, The broadcast messages arn't being received. Anyone got any idea?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private IRThread irThread;

    private Handler handler;
    private boolean onOff = false;
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> codeLookup = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        codeLookup.put(R.id.up_button, AuraGlowCodes.BRIGHTNESS_UP);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.down_button, AuraGlowCodes.BRIGHTNESS_DOWN);

        codeLookup.put(R.id.green_button, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_GREEN);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.red_button, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_RED);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.blue_button, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_BLUE);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.red_button_2, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_RED_2);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.blue_button_2, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_BLUE_2);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.green_button_2, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_GREEN_2);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.red_button_3, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_RED_3);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.blue_button_3, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_BLUE_3);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.green_button_3, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_GREEN_3);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.red_button_4, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_RED_4);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.blue_button_4, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_BLUE_4);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.green_button_4, AuraGlowCodes.COLOR_GREEN_4);

        codeLookup.put(R.id.flash_button, AuraGlowCodes.PATTERN_FLASH);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.fade_button, AuraGlowCodes.PATTERN_FADE);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.smooth_button, AuraGlowCodes.PATTERN_SMOOTH);
        codeLookup.put(R.id.strobe_button, AuraGlowCodes.PATTERN_STROBE);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        irThread = new IRThread(getApplicationContext());
        handler = irThread.getHandler();

        findViewById(R.id.onOff_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.up_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.down_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.red_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.green_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.blue_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.red_button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.green_button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.blue_button_2).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.red_button_3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.green_button_3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.blue_button_3).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.red_button_4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.green_button_4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.blue_button_4).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.flash_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.fade_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.strobe_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.smooth_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.e("[HERE]", "SENT BROADCAST");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int val = 0;

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.onOff_button:
                if (onOff){
                    val = AuraGlowCodes.TURN_OFF;
                } else {
                    val = AuraGlowCodes.TURN_ON;
                }
                onOff=!onOff;
                break;
            default:
                val = codeLookup.get(v.getId());
                break;
        }
        Log.wtf("[fuck]", Integer.toHexString(val));

        int[] pattern = NECFactory
                .createCommand()
                .addInteger(val, (byte)32)
                .getPattern(5);
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(IRThread.MSG_NAME, pattern);
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.github.dadude941.auraglowremote">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="io.github.dadude941.auraglowremote.ui.WidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

WidgetProvider.java:

```
package io.github.dadude941.auraglowremote.ui;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import io.github.dadude941.auraglowremote.R;

/**
 * Created by Miguel Boland on 06/03/2015.
 */
    public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public final static String WIDGET_ON_BUTTON = "MY_PACKAGE_NAME.WIDGET_BUTTON";
    public final static String WIDGET_OFF_BUTTON = "MY_PACKAGE_NAME.WIDGET_BUTTON2";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
        Log.e("[onUpdate]", "UPDATING");
        Intent intent = new Intent(WIDGET_ON_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.on_button, pendingIntent);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(WIDGET_OFF_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.off_button, pendingIntent2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        switch(intent.getAction()){
            case WIDGET_ON_BUTTON:
                Log.e("[onReceive]", "ON BUTTON");
                break;

            case WIDGET_OFF_BUTTON:
                Log.e("[onReceive]", "OFF BUTTON");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First don't send the broadcast Intent `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE`. This is sent by Android itself so you don't need to send it. Android sends this at device boot and periodically based on the configuration of your widget.

Also, you've broken your widget code by implementing both `onReceive()` and `onUpdate()`. `AppWidgetProvider` class is just a convenience class that does some processing for you. It extends `BroadcastReceiver` and overrides the `onReceive()` method. When the receiver is triggered and `onReceive()` is called, it extracts the ACTION and other parameters from the `Intent` and then calls one of `onUpdate()`, `onDeleted()`, `onEnabled()` or `onDisabled()`. Since you have overridden `onReceive()` in your  `WidgetProvider` class, your implementation will get called. Since your `onReceive()` method doesn't call `super.onReceive()` the `onReceive()` method of `AppWidgetProvider` will never get called which is why it will never call `onUpdate()`.

Possible solutions:

1) in `WidgetProvider.onReceive()`, if the ACTION isn't one that you are interested in, make sure to call `super.onReceive()` to give the super class a chance to do its thing.

2) Create a separate class to handle the broadcast Intents that you are sending (ie: `WIDGET_ON_BUTTON` and `WIDGET_OFF_BUTTON`) and don't use your `WidgetProvider` class to handle these. It just confuses things.